# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs at startup after installing CUDA toolkit 7.5

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda

After installing CUDA toolkit 7.5.18 on my Ubuntu 14.04.4 system using the offline deb process (outlined [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation)) I've found that when I reboot my system I got stuck at the Ubuntu splash screen.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or other key combinations doesn't appear to work but I can still SSH to the box and looking at my `/var/log/boot.log` all I can see is "OK"'s up until:

```
Restoring resolver state...
```

If I do (via SSH):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then reboot, everything returns to normal. Installing an older version of the toolkit (7.0) produces the same result (including successful rollback).

In Section 4.2 of the [install guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/doc/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf), I've noticed the warning regarding overwriting libGL.so when installing Mesa, and that there's an option (`--no-opengl-libs`) which can be used when installing via the runfile approach to prevent the overwrite. Since I'm not sure if this is the problem, I'd like to see if there's another solution via the deb method before trying the runfile approach.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated as I'm a bit of a noob.

Answer (score 0):

*Update*

Sigh.. Jumped the gun too soon. I was reading [this](https://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/) and noticed that when I viewed /etc/X11/xorg.conf I had:

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "layout"
Screen 0 "nvidia"
 Inactive "intel"
EndSection

This is even though my single monitor is connected to the onboard display adapter for my Intel card. So doing:

sudo service lightdm stop
sudo prime-select intel

as mentioned on that page then editing the config file section to be (not really sure if the previous 2 commands were even needed):

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "layout"
Screen 0 "intel"
Inactive "nvidia"
EndSection

And then rebooting seems to have solved the problem. Hopefully this helps save some time for someone..

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to try making CUDA work again, but in order to fix booting I pressed CTRL+ALT+5 to bring me to another terminal (after the boot hang), logged in, and issued the commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge "nvidia-*"
sudo apt-get purge "cuda-*"
sudo reboot
```

And I have a (fully) booting system again.